# how to write custom timeZone for scheduled functions for SA

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a scheduled function, but with Saudi Arabia, Riyadh TimeZone

I know that the function should be like this:

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') 
  .onRun((context) => {

});
```

but I don't know how to replace 'America/New_York' with my time zone (Saudi Arabia, Riyadh)
I tried to write it like this: 'Saudi_Arabia/Riyadh' but I got an error.
Can you help me to write it for my time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the Schedule Cloud Functions [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function), "the value for timeZone must be a time zone name **from the tz database**".

You'll find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) the list of tz database timeZones and, based on this list, you should use the "Asia/Riyadh" timezone.

Comment: thank you thats helped!, but can you help me also to define the region?, for example unctions.region("europe-west6")....., how can write it for my country?

Comment: What do you not understand with declaring the region? How to declare it or how to find the list of avalaible regions? The list of regions is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations?hl=en

Comment: I wanted the  list of regions thank you